# Trying to export a cloth simulation to a Collada file

Tags: animation, export, cloth-simulation, collada

I'm using an avatar and a skirt as .blend files and trying to create an animation as a cloth simulation (I followed this tutorial - http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-325838.html) with them on Blender, in which the avatar puts her skirt on. Now I'm trying to export the animation as a Collada (.dae) file and use WebGL (three.js) to render the animation. But the Collada file seems to not be working, since the browser (Safari) does not display the animation. How can I export this cloth simulation to a Collada file properly?

Comment: Did you try baking the animation and exporting the modelling/simulation properties? Also, Google Chrome is more reliable&stable for WebGL.

Comment: Yes, I baked the animation. There are not any options for exporting animation/simulation to Collada on Blender. I have tried to use Chrome, but it is not working either. I don't know if it is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found certain animations can be exported to .DAE format. (rotations, translations etc; basic stuff)

It just seems that cloth-animations is one of those that doesn't play nice unfortunately. Perhaps you can achieve what you want with the basic animations. Else I'd recommend using the .OBJ-format.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. I have conducted extensive research. It seems that a mesh animation (created on base of cloth simulation) just doesn't get exported to .dae. You have to try other formats or re-design the project unfortunately... Check out here: [Exporting cloth simulation to Collada results in static cloth instead of a waving one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101297/exporting-cloth-simulation-to-collada-results-in-static-cloth-instead-of-a-wavin)

Comment: Just to slightly add onto the answer above: certain animations can be exported (rotations, translations etc, I found, have no problem in the .DAE format). It just seems that cloth-animations is one of those that doesn't play nice unfortunately.